# Python postgresql LIMIT пропускает строки

Tags: sql, postgresql

Запрос такой

```
SELECT *
FROM records
      WHERE state='NULL'
      LIMIT 25
```

Выбирает 25 строк, но пропускает первую и 5-ую, при том, что state там = NULL
Потом обновил данные в выбранных строках, вот что получилось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Если не указана сортировка посредством `ORDER BY` то порядок выборки записей не определен и может быть произвольным